# How do I fix the UnboundLocalError?

Tags: programming, non-locality

I have read about the global and nonlocal variable and I know they may solve the problem, but as I'm still naive at this I couldn't figure out how to implement them to solve the UnboundLocalError. Sorry for the long program I put here:

```
 # initialization

import numpy as np

# import Qiskit

from qiskit import IBMQ, BasicAer
from qiskit.providers.ibmq import least_busy
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, execute
from qiskit.tools.jupyter import *
#provider= IBMQ.load.account()
 provider= IBMQ.load_account()

#import basic plot tools
from qiskit.visualization import plot_histogram
```

Here is the Dj function

```
 def dj_oracle(case, n):
#We need to make a QuantumCircuit object to return
#This circuit has n+1 qubits: the size of the input,
#plus one output qubit
oracle_qc=QuantumCircuit(n+1)

#First, let's deal with the case in which oracle is balanced

if case == "balanced":
    # We apply controlled-NOT gates for each qubit, using the
    #output qubit as target
    
    for qubit in range(n):
        oracle_qc.cx(qubit, n)
        
 # case in oracle is constant
if case == "constant":

# First decide what the fixed output of the oracle will be
# (either always 0 or always 1)
 
    output = np.random.randint(2)
    
if output == 1:
    
    oracle_qc.x(n)
    
oracle_gate = oracle_qc.to_gate()
oracle_gate.name ="Oracle"
return oracle_gate
```

and Here is the dj_algorithm

```
  def dj_algorithm(n, case='random'):
dj_circuit=QuantumCircuit(n+1, n)
# Set up the input register:
for qubit in range(n):
    dj_circuit.h(qubit)
#And set up the output qubit:
dj_circuit.x(n)
dj_circuit.h(n)
#Let's append the oracle gate to our circuit:

if case == 'random':
    random = np.random.randint(2)
    if random == 0:
        case = 'constant'
else: 
    case = 'balanced'
    oracle = dj_oracle(case, n)
    dj_circuit.append(oracle, range(n+1))
 # Finally, perform the H-gates again and measure:
for i in range(n):
        dj_circuit.h(i)
        dj_circuit.measure(i,i)
return dj_circuit
```

Now when I want to use the local simulator to get the results, I face the UnboundLocalError, Can anybody help me to solve it?

This is the error I get:

---

```
  UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
  <ipython-input-112-f0c5e2ae7e9a> in <module>
  2 backend = BasicAer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
  3 shots = 1024
  ----> 4 dj_circuit = dj_algorithm(n,'constant')
  5 results = execute(dj_circuit, backend=backend, shots=shots).result()
  6 answer = results.get_counts()

 <ipython-input-89-6104e1173619> in dj_algorithm(n, case)
 15     else:
 16         case = 'balanced'
 ---> 17         oracle = dj_oracle(case, n)
 18         dj_circuit.append(oracle, range(n+1))
 19      # Finally, perform the H-gates again and measure:

 <ipython-input-110-75bb51aa8b15> in dj_oracle(case, n)
 22         output = np.random.randint(2)
 23 
 ---> 24     if output == 1:
 25 
 26         oracle_qc.x(n)

 UnboundLocalError: local variable 'output' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Can you add the link to the description of the problem you are trying to solve? I think that would be helpful. Also, when you said you have `UnboundLocalError`, what is the description follows after that?

Comment: I am trying to reproduce the code : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iJX794qJIpY&t=1165s and I will add the error to the question. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Python related question. I think it should be asked in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)

This error happens because you try to check the value of the variable `output` before assigning a value to it.

As you may know, Python is space sensitive. Hence, the line where you check if `output` equals 1 will be executed regardless of `case` value. On the other hand,
the variable `output` will be initialized only if `case` equals `"constant"`.

This means this error will happen whenever `case` equals `"balanced"`